# Selenium issue with WaitForPageToLoad , FindElement, WebDriverWait

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running Cucumber with Selenium using Junit4. 
Testing a war based website with a chrome browser.

I'm facing this problems:

1. `WaitForPageToLoad` seems not wait for the page to load
2. `WebDriverWait` - Always waits the full time of the **timeout** parameter given, even if the **ExpectedConditions** was validated sooner.

for example:

`new WebDriverWait( DefaultDriver.getWebDriver(), 4 ).until(                    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated( locator.getBy() ) );`

3. `WebElement.findElement` - doesn't wait at all for the element to be visible

The result is that the scenario next step, fails on validating the elements are visible.

Any idea what might be the issue?

Additional info:
cucumber-junit-1.2.5, 
cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5, 
selenium-3.4.0, 
selenium-chrome-driver-3.4.0

Comment: Please add respective code so members can understand the problem.

Comment: Have you used ImplicitWait in your code?

Comment: Yes, ImplicitWait is used:

webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 400L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );

Comment: Do add more details. For a starter add a small snippet so that it is easy to find the issue, what's the error you got? What's the browser version, chromedriver version? os? selenium version?

Comment: Done.

Additional info: cucumber-junit-1.2.5, cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5, selenium-3.4.0, selenium-chrome-driver-3.4.0